# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) - C, CLion But There Is Nothing Wrong With the Output

Tags: c, clion, exit-code

I've done a project in which I needed to calculate the multiplications of very large numbers using LinkedList. However, even though I get the right answers I got an error message.

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

This happens whenever one of the numbers is really large. I've looked at old posts but I couldn't find anything similar to my situation.

Here are the example outputs.

[Example with error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elWyc.png)
[Example without error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGNJH.png)

I store the numbers in a LinkedList as digits. So, every node has a digit and there shouldn't be any issue about int/long thing I guess but I couldn't find what makes this. When I debug the code, I get the error pointer at the end of the code, where there is no code.
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skE6V.png)

I hope I explained my problem properly, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: I suspect this is because your program is being terminated by a signal.

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code `0xC0000005` means "access violation" in Microsoft Windows, which is the equivalent of a Linux "segmentation fault".

The problem is probably the following code:

```
char num1[] = "";

[...]

printf( "Num1: " );
gets( num1 );
```

This will cause a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) if the user enters anything more than an empty line. That is because the array `num1` only has room for a single character (which is already needed for the null terminating character).

I suggest that you use the following code instead:

```
char num1[100];

[...]

printf( "Num1: " );
fgets( num1, sizeof num1, stdin );
```

The code related to `num2` has the same problem.

I strongly suggest that you read this:

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/12149471)